# Google Maps iOS SDK with custom URLSessionConfiguration

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, firebase, nsurlsessionconfiguration

Since iOS 11 we can set:

```
let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
sessionConfiguration.multipathServiceType = .interactive
```

Then when WiFi connection is too slow, the app will automatically switch to cellular network, so HTTP requests will work fine. I need that because I use WeyeFeye device, so user's device is always connected to a WeyeFeye WiFi that doesn't work (we need it only to gain files from WeyeFeye).

So when I set this `.interactive` `URLSessionConfiguration` my application can do regular REST requests to our backend. But `google map` doesn't work, because it uses `URLSessionConfiguration.default` session configuration.

Is there any way to pass a session configuration to `Google Maps`.

**Update:**

I have the same issue with `Firebase` framework

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything obvious.  If you can't find one, either, you should file a bug against the SDK and ask for them to expose a configuration object that you can use to provide a custom session configuration as a baseline.

In the meantime, unless you can find some way to control what session is used, I think the only other way to solve this is with [swizzling](https://blog.newrelic.com/2014/04/16/right-way-to-swizzle/).

Basically, you would replace the getter method in the NSURLSessionConfiguration class with a custom implementation that always returns the value you want it to return.  After that, all sessions created in your app will use that mode.